# Can't format content of Rich Text Editor in Template

Tags: templates, editor, formatting

I use following functions to add a new rich text editor in admin .

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'adding_new_metaabox' );              
function adding_new_metaabox() 
{   
    add_meta_box('html_myid_61_section', 'ویژگی ها', 'my_output_function');
}

function my_output_function( $post ) 
{
    //so, dont ned to use esc_attr in front of get_post_meta
    $valueeee2 = get_post_meta($_GET['post'], 'PLUGIN_VALUE' , true ) ;
    wp_editor( htmlspecialchars_decode($valueeee2), 'mettaabox_ID_stylee', $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'MyInputNAME') );
}


function save_my_postdata( $post_id ) 
{                   
    if (!empty($_POST['MyInputNAME']))
    {
        $datta=htmlspecialchars($_POST['MyInputNAME']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'PLUGIN_VALUE', $datta );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_my_postdata' );
```

and I use this code to display the content in the template.

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "PLUGIN_VALUE", true);?>
```

but can't display clean content in the post. It looks like this:

```
<ul><li>Can't</li><li>Display</li><li>good</li></ul>
```

I don't want to actually display the tags I want to display the content in HTML, similar to the example below:

- Can't
- Display
- good

Answer (score 0):

Good question for your first question! Try running the variable through [`the_contnet` Filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) - You can use it like this:

```
$editor_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "PLUGIN_VALUE", true ); 
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', htmlspecialchars_decode( $editor_value ) );
```

I believe what's happening is that whenever you save your postmeta, it is being escaped as it should and converted to special characters [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) so that it can properly be saved to the database. By running the decode it should output the expected HTML.

Comment: @Mortzea Does it still show the same content ( with the HTML ) or was there an error?

Comment: it still show the same content ( with the HTML )  ///  in your code where called this variable $editor_value ?

Comment: @Mortzea - I am just storing the value returned from  `get_post_meta()` into a varibale I created called `$editor_value` so that we can use it inside our filter. See if the edited code works for you.

Comment: no. not working